# Hilt - Dependency cycle crash

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

If I just use the AuthRepository class in a single UseCase it's fine. However, if I try to use it in both AuthUseCase and RefreshTokenUseCase as in the example, I get an error.

Any suggestions other than using `Lazy<>` ?

Any help will be appreciated.

-

**Error**

-

```
App_HiltComponents.java:139: error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements App_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      AppRepository is injected at
          RefreshTokenTokenUseCase(authRepository)
      RefreshTokenTokenUseCase is injected at
          AppAuthenticator(refreshTokenTokenUseCase)
          ......
          ...
          ..
      AuthUseCase(authRepository)
      AuthUseCase is injected at
          MainViewModel(authUseCase, …)
               MainViewModel is injected at
          MainViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
```

- 

**My Code**

-

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Data.url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthAPI(
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): AuthAPI = retrofit.create(AuthAPI::class.java)
}


@Singleton
class AuthRepository @Inject constructor(
    private var authAPI: AuthAPI,
) {

}

@Singleton
class AuthUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository
) : UseCase<Response?, AuthUseCase.Params>() { 

}

@Singleton
class RefreshTokenUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository
) : UseCase<String?, RefreshTokenUseCase.Params>() { 

}
```

Comment: try to remove @Singleton annotations from your use cases.

Comment: Why not `Lazy` though? It seems like an OK solution to break this dependency cycle.

Comment: @rost thank but not solution

Comment: @AlexKrupa I did it with Lazy but it took a long time. If you have other solution or you can give a concise example with lazy. I'm glad you share.

Comment: Could you edit your post to also include `AppAuthenticator` and full dependency cycle from the error message? Is there perhaps an `OkHttpClient` somewhere on the way that uses that authenticator?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Provider<T>` instead of `Lazy` and than call `.get()` on it.

```
@Singleton
class RefreshTokenUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepositoryProvider: Provider<AuthRepository>
) : UseCase<String?, RefreshTokenUseCase.Params>() { 
    fun getRefreshToken() = authRepositoryProvider.get().getRefreshToken() //example of usage
}
```

This means `RefreshTokenUseCase` will be created before `AuthRepository` is created and later on it will receive singleton `AuthRepository` instance it needs.
For more complete explanation check this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70635400/6845311).